# Is it possible to get keys from Laravel array-syntax inputs?

Tags: php, laravel, forms

Given a form in the format:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('post') }}">
{{ csrf_field() }}
@foreach([
    'firstname' => 'First name',
    'lastname' => 'Last name',
] as $key => $label)
    <label for="person[{{ $key }}]">{{ $label }}</label>
    <input name="person[{{ $key }}]" id="person[{{ $key }}]" type="text" />
@endforeach
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

And a model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Person extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
    ];
}
```

I would like to use Laravel's `Illuminate\Http\Request::input()` function to retrieve all the `person` fields from the form and fill the model from it.

The example route that I used to test this functionality is:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Person;

Route::post('/testcase', function(Request $request) {
    $person = new Person;
    $fields = $request->input('person.*');
    $person->fill($fields);
    var_dump(
        $person->firstname,
        $person->lastname,
        $fields
    );
    return response('');
})->name('post');
```

However, this returns the following response:

```
NULL
NULL
array(2) {
[0]=>
string(4) "John"
[1]=>
string(3) "Doe"
}
```

(Where the form was filled with the values, "firstname" => "John" and "lastname" => "Doe")

Is it possible to retrieve the array inputs from this form with their corresponding keys ("firstname" and "lastname") instead of numerical keys, or will I have to specify all the keys manually?

Comment: try adding value="{{ $label }}" in the blade view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the way you access the input to

```
$fields = $request->input("person");
```

You should get

```
array:2 [▼
  "firstname" => "John"
  "lastname" => "Doe"
]
```

You should have no issue filling those fields with that logic. If you're trying to create multiple people in a single post, you'd need to use an extra index on your form:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  @foreach(['firstname' => 'First Name', 'lastname' => 'Last Name'] as $key => $label)
  <label for="person[0][{{ $key }}]">{{ $label }}</label>
  <input name="person[0][{{ $key }}]" id="person[0][{{ $key }}]" type="text" />
  @endforeach
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

And on the backend, in a loop, access as:

```
for($request->input("person") AS $index => $fields){
  $person = new Person;
  $person->fill($fields);
}

// OR

$fields = $request->input("person.0");
$person = new Person;
$person->fill($fields);
```

You'd need a way to maintain indices on the frontend when dynamically creating fields, but that's a different issue.